# In ctexbook document class, when I write a chapter, the word "chapter" is in English

Tags: books, chinese, ctex

I am writing a Chinese book using `ctexbook`, but when I used the chapter command, it does not write the word "chapter" in Chinese. Here's my code:

```
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 9in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{pxfonts}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{tkz-base}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\pagestyle{plain}
\setlength{\unitlength}{0.5cm}
\usepackage{accents}
\newcommand{\varvec}[1]{\underaccent{\tilde}{#1}}
\newcommand{\placenum}[1]{\makebox(1,1){#1}}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
            \node[shape=circle,draw,inner sep=1pt] (char) {#1};}}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\makeatletter
\pgfkeys{
  /tkzlabelX/no zero/.style={
    /tikz/xlabel style/.append style={
      style/.expand once={\ifdim\tkz@pos pt=0pt shape=coordinate\fi}}},
  /tkzlabelY/no zero/.style={
    /tikz/ylabel style/.append style={
      style/.expand once={\ifdim\tkz@pos pt=0pt shape=coordinate\fi}}},
  /tkzAxeXY/no zero/.code=, /tkzdrawX/no zero/.code=, /tkzdrawY/no zero/.code=,
  /tkzlabelX/make an O/.style={
    /tikz/xlabel style/.append style={
      style/.expand once={\ifdim\tkz@pos pt=0pt
        shape=rectangle, fill=none, fill/.code=, % no filling, please
        pos=.5, yshift=+3pt, anchor=south east, % counter default xlabel style
        inner sep=+.3333em, /utils/exec=\def\tkz@Xresult{$O$}\fi}}},
  /tkzAxeXY/make an O/.code=, /tkzlabelY/make an O/.code=,
  /tkzdrawX/make an O/.code=, /tkzdrawY/make an O/.code=}
\makeatother
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=black,
    filecolor=purple,      
    urlcolor=RoyalBlue,
    pdfpagemode=FullScreen,
}
\newcommand{\nc}{\newcommand}
\nc{\opta}{\textbf{A) }}
\nc{\optb}{\textbf{B) }}
\nc{\optc}{\textbf{C) }}
\nc{\optd}{\textbf{D) }}
\nc{\boxa}{\boxed{\textbf{A)}}}
\nc{\boxb}{\boxed{\textbf{B)}}}
\nc{\boxc}{\boxed{\textbf{C)}}}
\nc{\boxd}{\boxed{\textbf{D)}}}
\nc{\longdots}{\dots\dots\dots\dots}
\nc{\q}{Question }
\nc{\que}{\textbf{Question: }}
\nc{\ans}{\textbf{Answer: }}
\nc{\nms}{\normalsize}
\nc{\underlinefive}{\underline{\ \ \ \ \ }}
\nc{\underlineten}{\underline{\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ }}
\nc{\underlinetwenty}{\underlineten\underlineten}
\nc{\underlinethirty}{\underlinetwenty\underlineten}
\nc{\underlineforty}{\underlinethirty\underlineten}
\nc{\qqquad}{\qquad\quad}
\nc{\qqqquad}{\qquad\qquad}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\sectionfont{\fontsize{18}{15}\selectfont}
\subsectionfont{\fontsize{15}{15}\selectfont}
\subsubsectionfont{\fontsize{13}{15}\selectfont}

\usepackage{titlesec}


\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
   \begin{center}
       \vspace*{1cm}

       \Huge
       \textbf{中国高中数学}\\

       \vspace{2cm}
       
       \LARGE
       \textbf{2023 高一上}\\

       \vspace{1cm}

       第1 -- 13课
       
            
   \end{center}
\end{titlepage}

\newpage

\phantom{a} \pagenumbering{gobble}

\newpage

\pagenumbering{roman}
\LARGE
\tableofcontents

\newpage

\phantom{a} \pagenumbering{gobble}

\newpage

\normalsize \pagenumbering{arabic}

\chapter{集合中的常用思想}

\section{元素与集合}

\vspace{1cm}

\subsection{知识点睛}

\vspace{1em}


\end{document}
```

Could anyone please help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Don't use `sectsty`. You should customize your section style by `ctexbook` or `ctex.sty`. Please read the doc of `ctex`.

Comment: don't load so many packages. It doesn't make any sense to load txfonts, pxfonts, lmodern one after the other or to load both sectsty and titlesec. You only run into hard to debug problems if you overload your code like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simplify your code and reduce unnecessary packages, otherwise you will get wrong results.

```tex
\documentclass{ctexbook}
\begin{document}
\chapter{test}
\end{document}
```

Going back to your problem, your problem is that you loaded the `sectsty` package.

```tex
\documentclass{ctexbook}
\usepackage{sectsty}

\begin{document}
\chapter{test}
\end{document}
```